How can i click a button within a specific div in python selenium
<div class="account-container loggedIn svelte-2hymnw"><button type="button" class="text-center font-medium focus-within:ring-4 focus-within:outline-none inline-flex items-center justify-center px-5 py-2.5 text-sm rounded-lg icon-btn"><span class="sr-only">Account</span> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" class="shrink-0 w-4 h-4 nav-icon" role="img" aria-label="user solid" viewBox="0 0 14 18"><path fill="currentColor" d="M7 9a4.5 4.5 0 1 0 0-9 4.5 4.5 0 0 0 0 9Zm2 1H5a5.006 5.006 0 0 0-5 5v2a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-2a5.006 5.006 0 0 0-5-5Z"></path></svg></button></div>

This is the button within a div. It dont have a specific identifier.
I try already:
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='account-container.loggedIn']/button[1]").click()

The span within has a text which is found, but its not clickable.
Can someone help me out ?
TIA

can u sent link of website, and can u post if there is error ?

You can use that too. Better to use CSS_SELECTOR.
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".account-container .loggedIn .svelte-2hymnw button")


let me try that. Thanks for your answer. I didnt try it with the CSS Selector.

Thank you it did work. Just so simple and i waste like 2h for that. Thank you mate !

happy to hear that. @Kai better to use CSS_SELECTOR always. Happy coding

it's recommended to copy the XPath from the inspect tool in the browser
check copy XPath from browser
and a better format for the code is
try:
    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='account-container.loggedIn']/button[1]")))
    button.click()
finally:
    driver.quit()

